# Linux doesn't boot with hyperthreading enabled

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, udev

I've had this problem since 2.6.39: my computer won't boot without disabling hyperthreading in the bios. I'm using 3.6.6 now and still have the same problem. The only thing I can add to the description, that it hangs early in the boot process (processing udev).

I think it has to do with [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38262) bug, but it hasn't been updated since April. Any ideas?

Earlier kernels (<2.6.39) still boot fine with hyperthreading.

Comment: Tell us about your hardware, particularly your motherboard and BIOS. Does the `processor.nocst` workaround solve it for you?

Comment: This is my ACPI dump with HT disabled in the BIOS (linux won't boot otherwise):
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=72108

Comment: BIOS Information
 Vendor: Award Software International, Inc.
 Version: F1
 Release Date: 08/04/2009
 Address: 0xE0000
 Runtime Size: 128 kB
 ROM Size: 2048 kB

Comment: Motherboard: Gigabyte P55-US3L

Comment: The processor.nocst workaround doesn't work for me.

Comment: I ***doubt*** that something this central is br0ked in the kernel. Fix your configuration under "processor type and features" or use some stock kernel that is known to work for your CPU. Also, add details about your hardware, otherwise all answers will be guesses and as correct as my next guess: There is an alligator in your computer eating your Hyperthreads.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин: well in the bug I linked something this central was borked in the kernel...

Comment: uh-huh. Status:  CLOSED PATCH_ALREADY_AVAILABLE